# Which parsec-like libraries for OCaml are recommended for actual use?

Tags: parsing, ocaml, parsec

The Google tells me there are several parsec-like libraries for OCaml: Batteries' ParserCo, Planck, Mparser, PCL, and ocaml-parsec.  My problem is knowing which one to choose.  Can someone give me some feedback concerning stability, active maintenance, quality of documentation, etc?

Comment: this is a very open ended question. Usually, these questions are better asked on http://programmers.stackexchange.com.  Although, maybe if there is someone here who knows all the libs you mention...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have a vague idea of how ParserCo, Planck and PCL look like, and I would start from Planck, expecting to find some rough edges and evolve the library a bit myself over use. None of them are really actively documented, but Planck got some "serious" test cases (parsing the OCaml grammar itself) and the developer, Jun Furuse, is reactive may be interested in getting it upto shape.

That said, parsing combinator libraries are not that popular in the OCaml world. We still quite actively use parser generators. If you don't have strong opinions either way, I recommend that you have a try at [Menhir](http://gallium.inria.fr/~fpottier/menhir/), that is quite polished and nice to use (and also actively maintained).

Comment: After I played with parsing OCaml 3.12.1, I maintain Planck for 4.00.1 but never tested it again against OCaml compiler source. It should be ok. I also recommend to use the good and old lex+yacc in OCaml.